# Extending global var in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, module-augmentation

I'm trying to implement a [`Response.json` static method](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues?q=response.json) polyfill. `Response` (not the interface, the class/constructor) is declared in `lib.dom.d.ts`. If it was defined with an interface like this:

```
declare var Response: ResponseConstructor;

interface ResponseConstructor {
  prototype: Response;
  new (body?: BodyInit | null, init?: ResponseInit): Response;
  error(): Response;
  redirect(url: string | URL, status?: number): Response;
};
```

I could have easily extended it in my own `d.ts` like this:

```
declare global {
  interface ResponseConstructor {
    json(data: any, init?: ResponseInit): Response;
  };
}
```

But it's defined like this instead:

```
declare var Response: {
  prototype: Response;
  new (body?: BodyInit | null, init?: ResponseInit): Response;
  error(): Response;
  redirect(url: string | URL, status?: number): Response;
};
```

Now when I try to extend it:

```
declare global {
  var Response: {
    json(data: any, init?: ResponseInit): Response;
  };
}
```

I get the following error:

`Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Response' must be of type '{ new (body?: BodyInit | null | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string | URL, status?: number | undefined): Response; }', but here has type '{ json(data: any, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; }'.`

[Playground reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUBNgGMA2BDKYOAcxwgCM8dEU44A3AuAJWAGdIA7N4ALhrp0AVmwicAFOjww8-PJwCeAGjgBLTqpgB+fqw5ieASQ0wAlLvZceAblpwkt1Cj1XgAOhFi4AXjgAzAFdOLBhVL08JKRk5RRV1TR0WSwNgY01TAUF4+F9suAAffMQHOzpstwALYDxMKDYfOE5gAHc4AAlq2rZxcqqa4DrTW0E1PzhxAEJezoG2SrxugCIAYTEYYE4YAFoAFQUwYEXTDIRSkbUTSpm6tx4YcRW1je29g8WVRbwwMBxVLGkwpwAPQRI7DQROEaEGABKCcRotJL6bjAcQAKQAygB5ABytxgUHUxFUfgUkmkeFMcRMQxQqCAA)

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: GitHub issues at [ms/TS#4062](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4062)  and [ms/TS#37771](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37771).  There's no direct support for this; You could *try* using an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZabW), but that only works in the scope the function is called in.  Maybe the right thing is to just change lib.dom.d.ts locally (maybe with `ResponseConstructor`) and try to advocate for upstream changes?

Comment: Yeah, I though that much. Thank you for digging up the issues which I failed to find!